# eclipse does not properly parse and index C++

Tags: eclipse, parsing, indexing, eclipse-cdt

My eclipse kepler running on Ubuntu often throws parsing error, thought my makefile compiles the project correctly. For example the following throws an error , while makefile runned from terminal compiles it fine:

```
boost::optional<std::string> str = std::string("xmldata/swpa_msg.sig.xml");
EXPECT_EQ("xmldata/swpa_msg.sig.xml", *str);
```

the second line is underline by eclipse throwing:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
testing::AssertionResult Compare(const char *, const char *, const #10000 &, const #10001   &)
testing::AssertionResult Compare(const char *, const char *, long long int, long long int)
```

This is only one of many issues. I tried Project -> c++ Index -> rebuild, but it does not work. This is annoying because every time i would like to compile my project a have to run makefile from terminal and remove my errors thrown in terminal. I am wasting a lot of time because of this. Previosly I have coded in Java in eclipse and there wasn't such problem.
Any ideas ? Thanks.